# My Windows 7 is not genuine

Tags: windows-7, windows, license

I have installed Windows 7 a week ago. Now when I open my laptop and enter the password of my account, a message shows up says "Windows is not genuine" and it asks me if I want to "Get genuine now". so when I choose to get genuine, another message ask me to: "1-Buy a new product key online. 2-Type a different product key ".

Note: I installed the same version of Windows on another laptop, but I did not have this problem.

Does it have to do with the PC type? What should I do?

Comment: please run the Microsoft Genuine Diagnostics Tool (MGADiag) from here:http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=52012. Inside the tool click "Copy" and paste the output here.

Comment: Could you clarify if you have used the same license key on the 2 different computers?

Comment: @David yes i did

Comment: We cannot help with pirated software.

Answer (score 2):

You have used the same license key on 2 different computers, which you are not permitted to do.  You are in breach of the license terms.  Microsoft Windows has detected this, and therefore notifying you of this problem.

Unfortunately, you will need to buy yourself a second license.  You can either do this online through the link "1-Buy a new product key online" that is presented to you, or purchase a license through another seller, either online like Amazon, or a local computer shop.

Comment: maybe i didn't mention that this version of windows is not official, and in my country we can't buy over the internet.Thanks.

Comment: Annoyingly, you will have to get a different key.  I can only recommend that you purchase it.  Or, use a different operating system like Linux where you will not have this problem.

Comment: very annoying but i used to it. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Sana - If you don't have a valid license there is nothing we can do.  We can only help people with an actual license to Windows.  There are tons of free operating systems I suggest one of those.